# Product Carousal for desktop and mobile? (Css,Javascript,html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a product carousal. i have used swiper.js but it is not working 
i have set of 4 products show in a row and i want to make a carousal for mobile too having only 1 product in one row and swipe to see others
here is my code

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
      <div class="swiper-container">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <?php while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
                $wc_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide mob mx-auto col-md-2">
            <div class="border-box">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <center><h3 class="box-bottom"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><h3>PKR:<?php echo                  $product->get_price();?></a></h3></h3></center>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php else:  ?>
        <li>
        <?php _e( 'No Products' ); ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?> 
      </div>
```

JS CODE

```
  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
// Optional parameters
direction: 'horizontal',
loop: true,

// Navigation arrows
navigation: {
  nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},

// And if we need scrollbar
scrollbar: {
  el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
},
```

})

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible code for the community members to give you right direction. However, from you question it seems you are looking for `breakpoint` object. Check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-demo-37-responsive-breakpoints?file=index.html

Comment: @ismi i have tried this (swiper.js) but every time i use it my row of product disappear

Comment: If you can post minimal reproducible code or HTML equivalent to PHP code will help community members to look into your swiper implementation.

Comment: @ismi please check i have updated my code